# dynamically modify data-filtertext in jquery filtered list

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a filtered jquery list like this :

```
<ul id="myFilteredList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
  <li data-theme="b"  id="Li0" data-filtertext="selected_"><a href="#">Li element 1 </a></li>
  <li data-theme="b"  id="Li1" data-filtertext="selected_"><a href="#">Li element 2 </a></li>
  <li data-theme="b"  id="Li2" data-filtertext="selected_"><a href="#">Li element 3 </a></li>
  <li data-theme="b"  id="Li3" data-filtertext="selected_"><a href="#">Li element 4 </a></li>
  <li data-theme="b"  id="Li4" data-filtertext="selected_"><a href="#">Li element 5 </a></li>
</ul>
```

attribute **data-filtertext="selected_"** can be changed programtically as this (**data-filtertext="selected_ blocked_"**)

```
<li data-theme="b"  id="Li4" data-filtertext="selected_ blocked_"><a href="#">Li element 5 </a></li>
```

using this code:

```
$('#myFilteredList').children('#Li4').attr('data-filtertext', 'selected_ blocked');
$('#myFilteredList').listview('refresh');
```

The problem is when I try to filter **blocked** elements it don´t show **Li element 5**, what I'm missing ?

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/SU6xY/

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to Demo.
2. Type blocked at filter bar, the results show Lielement 2
3. Press Alter Filter button, it changes li2 element filter to none and li4 element filter to blocked.
4. Type again blocked at filter bar, it still shows Lielement 2 , it must show Lielement 4

It only works if the list are never filtered. If you try to filter and then apply new data-filtertext, the filter doesn't work.

Comment: A jsfiddle demonstration would be very helpful

Comment: I don't know about your code, but *in your question* that's what you're missing: the jQuery. Can you show us what you're doing?

Comment: where's the filtering code?

Comment: Ok .. i'm going to put the Jsfiddle

Comment: The jsFiddle allready available.

Comment: There is no filtering code , just use data-filter="true" at list definition **<ul data-filter="true"></ul>**

Answer (score 2):

Lose:

```
$('#myFilteredList').listview('refresh');
```

You don't need it here, it is used to restyle a listview.

Without it it is working in my jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/5f3By/

If your content is added dynamically then modify data-filtertext after a listview refresh.

Comment: Tks, do you know why this happens?. If add some new elements to the list ('refresh') is not neccesary ?

Comment: You need to refresh after adding a new element, but change li attribute data-filtertext after a listview refresh.

Comment: Just an issue, it only works if none filter was applyed before the data-filtertext is changed?.. any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the solution but you could perhaps try using the jQuery .data() method to change the data attribute's value?

http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Tks for your help, but reading the api docs, it cant't help with my problem.